# Passing a number object between two tableview controllers: IOS

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, parameter-passing

I'm a newbie trying to pass the row number selected from a table in view controller 1, to the to a second view controller.

I'm attempting to do this using a property declaration for the number in VC1:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *passedSectorNumber;
```

It is then @synthesized in VC1 and set with the appropriate row number in the didSelectRowatIndexPath of VC1 thus:

```
self.passedSectorNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[indexPath row]];
        VC2 *vc2 = [[SectorEditor alloc] initWithNibName:@"vc2nibname" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
        [vc2 release];
```

In VC2 I also define a NSNumber property with the same name, and sythesize it.

In VC2 also:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *passedSectorNumber;
```

I test the passed value in VC 2 thus:

```
NSInteger intvalue = [self.passedSectorNumber integerValue];
    NSLog(@"The value of the integer is: %i", intvalue);
```

The number "received" in VC2 is always '0', irrespective of which row is selected.

I'm making a rookie error. Any idea where? Very grateful for input.

Comment: In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you need to do: `vc2.passedSectorNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row];` after you alloc-init `vc2`. For that, you need the property `passedSectorNumber` to be declared in VC2. You  do not need to declare a property `passedSectorNumber` in VC1.

Comment: do you have `vc2.passedSectorNumber = self.passedSectorNumber`?

Comment: >>albertamg, thanks, that worked very nicely. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your second VC is called SectorEditor:

```
self.passedSectorNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[indexPath row]];
VC2 *vc2 = [[SectorEditor alloc] initWithNibName:@"vc2nibname" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
[vc2 release];
```

Should be this:

```
VC2 *vc2 = [[SectorEditor alloc] initWithNibName:@"vc2nibname" bundle:nil];
vc2.passedSectorNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[indexPath row]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
[vc2 release];
```

Or even better, declare a class method in your second VC called initWithPassedNumber and inside that call the initWithNibName like this:

```
- initWithPassedSectorNumber:(NSInteger)sectorNumber
{
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:@"vc2nibname" bundle:nil])) {
         self.passedSectorNumber = sectorNumber
    }
}
```

Then the call to that would be something like this:

```
VC2 *vc2 = [[SectorEditor alloc] initWithPassedSectorNumber:indexPath.row bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
[vc2 release];
```

Haven't tested any code, but this is gonna be close to what you need.